# MVC display partial view on navigation bar click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, razorengine

I want to display the partial view, when I click on navigation bar click. I have a view which contains left side menu. when user click on navigation bar item, appropriate view should display.

I am not getting how can I implement such view?

**Manage.cshtml**

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>My Account</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-stacked-extended">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a id="A3" target="_self" runat="server" href="@Url.Action("Contactinfo", "Account")">Contact Info</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a id="A4" target="_self" runat="server" href="@Url.Action("changePassword", "Account")">Password</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 ng-scope" data-ng-view="">
                <div class="row row-gap-medium ng-scope">
                    @Html.Partial("Contactinfo")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In above code, I have created left side menu i.e contactinfo, changepassword etc. when `Manage.cshtml` load first time I want to display `Contactinfo` view. When user click on password menu, `contactinfo` get's changed with `changedpassword` page. Please check following screen shot. 
[image]

Here in above image you can see left side menu and appropriate page. What I want when user click on password, view changed to `password page`. Currently it shows contact info page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your requirement just make partial Views of the links present in your left side bar and when user clicks on a specific option in left side bar then just load a appropriate partial view from ajax call using jquery and just replace html of right side bar with the html coming from ajax call.

Give your left side menues unique id and then :

A Demo :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#menu1").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
                url: "/MyController/getdata",
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'html',
                data: {  },
                success: function (data) {
                   $("#div1").html('');
                   $("#div1").html(data);

            });
    });
});
```

Controller(MyController) :

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult getdata(string dropval)
{
//bind model here
return PartialView("mypartialview",model)
}
```

Comment: How can I pass partial view name? when I click on different menu option

Comment: I didn't think you needed to clear the current content with .html('') since .html(string) completely replaces the existing content.

Comment: suppose I have `<a id="A4" target="_self" runat="server" href="@Url.Action("changePassword", "Account")">Password</a>` when I click on it how can I pass changePassword as a view name? And when Page loads first it should display `contactinfo` view

Comment: @AjayPunekar..why are using runat server its mvc not webforms and with anchor tag just call  a function and then make a ajax call as shown above and in ajax call get url as var url = $(this).attr('href')

Comment: Actually firstly I developed this site in asp.net. So I just copied this from asp.net. That why you see runat

Comment: you have used `$("#menu1").click` in your code. So, I need to create this for all menu items?

Comment: @AjayPunekar..just give menues unique id and perform click or just make a function from all menues call that function and perform ajax call

Answer (score 0):

i think you should render partial through JavaScript.

Let's say you have `<div id="partialView"></div>`

Then you should run Ajax query when user clicked on link.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('yourUrl'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#partialView').html(result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can I pass partial view name? when I click on different menu option

Comment: My suggestion in use data-* attribute in your links. Like this: '<a href="#" data-partial="your url">info</a>' and then use attribute value in your js.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can give me `a` tag with `data-*` attribute?

Comment: Suppose you have **<a href="#" data-id="some value">link</a>** Then you can get attribute value with using **$(element).attr("data-id")** or **$(element).data("id")**

Answer (score 0):

Took me a little while to figure this out too.

Essentially, you want your Controller action to return a partial view, then use Ajax to load that returned partial view.

JavaScript / Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'viewName': 'password' },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#partial-container').html(data);
            }
        });
```

Controller return type

```
Public ActionResult GetView(string viewName)
{
    return PartialView(viewName, model);
}
```

Ideally, change your HTML so it's easier to reference the div container where you'd like to load the partial

```
<div class="col-xs-9 ng-scope" data-ng-view="">
                <div class="row row-gap-medium ng-scope">
                    <div id="partial-container">@Html.Partial("Contactinfo")</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: How can I pass partial view name? when I click on different menu option

Comment: pass it in the data part of the Ajax request, where I'm passing 'id', you could pass view name.

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect the change, so you're passing viewName in as the data of the ajax request, then the controller is passing that view back out in the response.

Comment: suppose I have `<a id="A4" target="_self" runat="server" href="@Url.Action("changePassword", "Account")">Password</a>` when I click on it how can I pass changePassword as a view name?

Comment: Format your href differently, just as a string, then you can use jquery to get the value from the anchor tag. So, if you change your anchor tag href to something like href="Account/ChangePassword", the jquery something like $('#A4').attr('href') as the data.

Answer (score 0):

try This JS for Clickevent

```
$(document).on('click', '#anCalcBtn', function () {
$('#anCalcDetail').load('/Home/Contactinfo/');
});
```

If I am not wrong you are trying to do like [This](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-10)

Comment: How can I pass partial view name? when I click on different menu option

Comment: They have created master page. I don't want to use master page.